# FileField is shown uploaded by django admin but not from views

Tags: python, django, boto, django-storage

I have installed boto with django to upload files to S3. All seems to work fine.

When I upload a file from the admin, the file is save it correctly in S3 and I can see it from the url, but when I upload the file from the views using a normal form in the template, the file is uploaded but it is not shown and I receive this message:

```
NoSuchKeyThe specified key does not exist.media/11831688_978787805518962_14148247639056529_n.jpgB818E754DFF35476K8HkTNpjQjft4dYb9cXH/f5SQrp1glnle11tvoW7SezMxNJvrDFuT/kzJ0z6N9G4sMNyr57c128=
```

My models:

```
class InteraccionFotos(models.Model):
    campana = models.ForeignKey(Campana)
    titulo_foto = models.ForeignKey('actividad_fotos.TitulosFotos')
    punto_interaccion = models.ForeignKey(PuntoInteraccion)
    foto = models.FileField(upload_to='.',blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.titulo_foto.titulo_foto)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

My form:

```
class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Upload files with this form"""
    class Meta:
        model = InteraccionFotos
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is my view:

```
class SubeFotoView(FormView):
    form_class = FileForm
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'tomar_fotos.html'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.save(commit=True)
        messages.success(self.request, 'File uploaded!')
        return super(SubeFotoView, self).form_valid(form)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        campana = self.kwargs.get('campana_id')
        point_id = self.kwargs.get('point_id')
        titulo_foto = request.POST['titulo']
        foto = request.FILES['foto']
        valida_foto = InteraccionFotos.objects.filter(campana_id=campana,punto_interaccion_id=point_id,titulo_foto_id=titulo_foto)
        for f in valida_foto:
            if f.foto:
                return HttpResponse("Ya subiste una foto")
            else:
                crea_foto = InteraccionFotos.objects.filter(campana_id=campana,punto_interaccion_id=point_id,titulo_foto_id=titulo_foto).update(foto=foto)          
                data = {}
                data['success'] = "Foto subida con exitosamente"
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<form action="/subir-fotos/{{campana_id}}/{{point_id}}/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"id="form_tomaFoto{{page}}">{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" value="{{p.titulo_foto.id}}" name="titulo">
            <p><input type="file" name="foto" required></p>
            <!--<div class="image-upload" align="center">
                <label for="file-input">
                <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/camera-icon-png-slr-camera-xxl.png" width="100px" />
                </label>-->
                <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar foto" class="boton"></p>
            </div>
            
        </form>
```

How can I achieve save correctly the file uploaded from the views as works in the admin?

Comment: Try to create a folder in upload_to="something"

Comment: @PierangeloOrizio Nothing happens if I add an specific folder. Actually, before post my question I had the path /fotos